# Functions with same name in different directives override each other

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular.js directive that renders some D3 charts:

```
angular.module('my-app.deltaChart', [])
.directive('deltaChart',
[ function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        scope : {
            data : '='
        },
        link : function(scope, element) {

            var container = element[0];
            var svg = d3.select(container)
                .append("svg");

            var render = function(data) {

                if (!data) {
                    return;
                }

                var bars = svg.selectAll("g");
                /**
                   etc...
                **/

            }

            scope.$watch("data", function(newData) {
                render(newData);
            }, true);

            render(scope.data);

 }}}]);
```

And I use this directive more than once in my code:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <delta-chart data="currentData.values"></delta-chart>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <delta-chart data="pastData.values"></delta-chart>
</div>
```

A user action in the DOM can change the contents of currentData.values and pastData.values via an `ng-click` function. However, only the last chart specified in the DOM updates to reflect the new data; the other `render` functions do not get called.

I eventually tracked this strange behavior down to the `render` function behaving like a global variable. I was under the impression that any variables declared in the directive's `link` function would be local in scope and instantiated anytime the directive was declared. However, the `render` function seems to behave like a global variable. Tying it to the directive's `scope` solved the problem:

```
        scope.render = function(data) {
                 ...
        }

        scope.$watch("data", function(newData) {
            scope.render(newData);
        }, true);
```

This proved true even with two different types of directives (both rendering charts in D3):

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <delta-chart data="currentData.values"></delta-chart>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <ring-chart data="otherData.values"></ring-chart>
</div>
```

If both had a function called `render`, only the last declared one would get called on variable updates.

Can anyone help me understand variable scoping in Angular.js directives?

Comment: please check this jsfiddle..[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bqs5ebd5/)..The render function here is getting called twice as expected..

Comment: Yes, you're right and a similar `alert` call in my application code shows both `render` functions are getting called with the new data. However, D3 only renders the last chart.

Comment: The question contains irrelevant parts and lacks [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). A plunker would help. In the case of a directive with isolated scope `var render = ` and `scope.render = ` are absolutely same things (the latter is more testable). If it is a problem of D3, the statement on `render` function is wrong. If this is a problem of directive function (though it is unlikely), calls should be tracked with `console.log` or debugger, not with D3 visual results.